# Adding a new property in google console or webmaster after purchasing a new domain

Tags: google-search-console

I revamped and redesigned my old website(OLDDOMAIN.COM) and I purchased a new domain. Here's my current GoogleWebmaster/Console setup or situation.

OLDomain.com is currently registered in google webmaster/console

Now that my site is live should I add another property and register my NEWDOMAIN.COM or I will continue to use OLDOMAIN.COM? Will it automatically sync knowing that I redirected my OLDdomain.com to my NEWDOMAIN.com

thanks to those who will contribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change of address tool. It should be within the cog on the right hand side of the screen.

> If you've moved your site to a new domain or subdomain, use the Change of address tool in Search Console. A change of address notification helps you manage the transition needed by Google to index your new URLs at the new address, while minimizing impact to your current ranking in Google Search results.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

Comment: I have tried using the change address but it's disabled. And also the account registered on GWT/Console is verified.

Comment: When you say its disabled do you mean it doesn't appear at all?

Comment: Here's the screenshot of google console http://i66.tinypic.com/2z6v0vn.png as you can see the buttons are disabled so I cannot proceed.

Comment: You need to click the link 'Add it now' in the top point. Here you will add your new domain and then continue with this list.

Comment: I have already added the new domain and still it shows NO AVAILABLE SITES http://i65.tinypic.com/nez2uv.png

Comment: thanks for your response @grapesoda I just able to redirect the address and enabled the SUBMIT BUTTON after adding another property and redoing the whole process.

Comment: I Added a NEW PROPERTY, And verified the NEWDOMAIN.COM via ANALYTICS CODE. After NEWDOMAIN.COM was verified the 2-4 steps were enabled see screen shot http://i65.tinypic.com/11uu8ea.png